# Problem with Python Conditionals and Altering Variables for ML Model in Flask App

Tags: python, machine-learning, flask, conditional-statements

Long time lurker, first time poster. I'm new to Python. I have created an ML model which works (sklearn, log reg). It expects 12 variables in an array and outputs a value.

I have used flask to create an app.py which interfaces with an HTML form. The user inputs are passed to the flask app and run though the model. The result is posted on the HTML form along with the inputs the user selected. The HTML form contained numerical inputs and radios. This has been working fine.

I've now changed the HTML form and substituted 5 of the radios for a drop down option. Before the radios would deliver 5 discrete values (of the 12 in total) (e.g. 0, 1, 0, 0, 0) which would be assigned to the variables using the request.form function:

Location_0
Location_1
Location_2
Location_3
Location_4

These would be fed into the model.

With the drop down option only one value is returned (0 or 1 or 2 or 3 or 4). Because the ML  model expects 5 discrete values I've tried to create a conditional which will define the variables:

```
    Location_0
    Location_1
    Location_2
    Location_3
    Location_4
```

e.g. if drop down returns 1, then:

```
    Location_0 = 0
    Location_1 = 1
    Location_2 = 0
    Location_3 = 0
    Location_4 = 0
```

Here is the code ive used to try and achieve this:

```
@app.route('/predict', methods=['POST'])
def predict():

    age = request.form['age']
    sex = request.form['sex']
    Hourstotreat = 200
    Sizemm = request.form['Stonesize']
    Side = request.form['laterality']
    HU = request.form['HU']
    Stonetoskin = request.form['skintostone']
    
#Below is the request for location which is a value returned from a drop down box. Value is #between 0-4

location = request.form['location']

#I read i need to define the variables prior to the conditional so did this. 

    Location_0 = 1
    Location_1 = 2
    Location_2 = 3
    Location_3 = 4
    Location_4 = 5

    def location():
        if location == 0:
            Location_0 = 1
            Location_1 = 0
            Location_2 = 0
            Location_3 = 0
            Location_4 = 0
        elif location == 1:
            Location_0 = 0
            Location_1 = 1
            Location_2 = 0
            Location_3 = 0
            Location_4 = 0
        elif location == 2:
            Location_0 = 0
            Location_1 = 0
            Location_2 = 1
            Location_3 = 0
            Location_4 = 0
        elif location == 3:
            Location_0 = 0
            Location_1 = 0
            Location_2 = 0
            Location_3 = 1
            Location_4 = 0
        elif location == 4:
            Location_0 = 0
            Location_1 = 0
            Location_2 = 0
            Location_3 = 0
            Location_4 = 1
    location()


    user_input = pd.DataFrame([[age, sex, Sizemm, Side, HU, Stonetoskin, Hourstotreat,
                                Location_0, Location_1, Location_2, Location_3, Location_4]],

                              columns=['age', 'sex', 'Sizemm', 'Side', 'HU', 'Stonetoskin', 'Hourstotreat',
                                       'Location_0', 'Location_1', 'Location_2', 'Location_3', 'Location_4'],
                              dtype=float,
                              index=['input'])

    new_data = np.array([user_input]).reshape(1, -1)
    result = model.predict_proba(new_data)[:, 1][0]
    resulttext = ("Probability of success of ESWL on first attempt is {:.2%}".format(result))

    return render_template('mainpage.html',
                           age=age,
                           sex=sex,
                           Sizemm=Sizemm,
                           HU=HU,
                           Side=Side,
                           Stonetoskin=Stonetoskin,
                           location=location,
                           location0=Location_0,
                           location1=Location_1,
                           location2=Location_2,
                           location3=Location_3,
                           location4=Location_4,
                           result=resulttext,
                           )
```

Upon trying this, only the pre defined values get fed into the model:

```
Location_0 = 1
Location_1 = 2
Location_2 = 3
Location_3 = 4
Location_4 = 5
```

Using the return render_template i can see that the correct value from the drop box is being fed back and that the variables are the pre defined ones.

I've tired not pre defining the variables and running this not in a function but it doesn't seem to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Success (thanks Chat GPT!)

I needed to use the function outside of the predict function.
I also made location_X variables global variables
Finally i renamed the function to assign_location(value) and recalled it in the predict function.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).